# Sympy does not simplify sine eulers formula

Tags: sympy

Why does it not simplify to zero?
Cosine seems to work. Why?

```
from sympy import *

 x = Symbol("x")
expr = (1/(2*I)) * (E**(I*x) - E**(-I*x))
print(simplify(expr - sin(x)))
```

Comment: @prgrm this seems to be a legitimate question about Sympy's simplification abilities.

Answer (score 3):

Sympy's simplification routines are necessarily heuristic, so you'll have to give them some hints. In this case, you can tell sympy to rewrite everything in terms of exponentials:

```
simplify((expr - sin(x)).rewrite(exp)) # 0
```